# Ranorex- Issue in casting Adapter to UIAutomation

Tags: c#, ranorex

I am creating an button for which I need an automation element,
creation

```
Adapter adapter= Host.Local.FindSingle<Adapter>(path)
```

then

```
var uiAutomation=adapter.As<UIAutomation>();
```

This conversion is unsuccessful.What I am doing wrong here, Is there any other way to get the automation element from adapter?
I need automation element to GetClickablePoint() and some other properties. 
Also have tested

```
Unknown unknown = path;
var uiAutomation = unknown.As<UIAutomation>()
uiAutomation.AutomationElement;
```

Which also returns null on casting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you actually want to do, but there are 3 different plug-ins in Ranorex for recognizing WPF elements. You only need the UIAutomation implementation if you want to use the WPF legacy setting. The question is why do you want to use the legacy plug-in?
Did you try to change the setting to WPF Improved][1](https://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/ranorex-settings/improved-wpf-plug-in.html)in the settings Dialog and check if the attributes are available?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have started working on Ranorex recently was not aware of this, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix Ranorex with UiAutomation.
Ranorex do not want you to use UiAutomation because you could avoid using their software.
If you still want to use Ranorex, it provides all the methods to interact with the adapters. The best thing is to investigate using their Ranorex studio : create a scenario, build it and look at the source code generated to undertand how to interact as it is clearly not obvious to do.